# Выбрать значение в выпадающем меню

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно, чтобы в выпадающем меню выбрали какое то значение и в зависимости от значения менялись вопросы. Как это сделать с `javascript`'ом? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я совсем не знаю javascipt так что мне все очень подробно=)

Comment: @Dikaz, если вы совсем не знаете javascipt, то у вас не вопрос, а заказ на выполнение работы.

Comment: хмм..ой я не подумал об этом...просто не хочется рыться в жаваскрипте для такой маловажной штучки(в моем случае)..на самом деле просто это единственная вещь которая нужна(хотелось бы как можно красивее преподу предоставить).а недельки через две сам начну изучать жаваскрипт тогда уже будут более серьезные вопросы.

Comment: @Dikaz, а в каком виде у вас храняться вопросы?

Comment: @Deonis, что [делают](http://tsya.ru/)?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, пора вам становиться экспертом [на этом форуме](http://russ.hashcode.ru/) )) Исправил ;)

Comment: @Deonis, это просто одна из самых популярных ошибок. Даже сайт специальный сделали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, пока вы обдумываете, как ответить на мой вопрос по поводу хранения ваших вопросов, вот вам [простой пример реализации](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Ktkfm/) на чистом JS. Хотя, если ваш преподаватель разрешает, то можно будет реализовать на jQuery.

Comment: я хотел хранить их в html коде, то есть у меня есть два блока.В начале их не видно и после выбора, допустим пола, вылезают эти вопросы.

Comment: @Dikaz, давайте не будем гадать, а выложите часть html-кода, относящегося к данной проблеме, на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: но ваш пример тоже очень даже меня устраивает.У меня есть вопрос, если мы впишем рядом с вопросами формы они будут восприниматься html'ом?

Comment: Вот

     <div class="i">Я</div>
     <select class="sel" name="status" size="1">
     <option value="tchr">Учитель</option>
     <option value="prnt">Родитель</option> 
     </select>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>

если учитель 

     ВУЗ: 
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="inst" SIZE="20"placeholder="МГУ" required />
     <br>
и т.д. и если родитель

     Номер телефона: 
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="inst" SIZE="20"placeholder="89*********" required />
     <br>

Comment: >> если мы впишем рядом с вопросами формы они будут восприниматься html'ом?
ответ: будут

Comment: тогда все.спасибо=)